# How to prevent deprecated flutter widgets suggestions in vs code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, intellisense, deprecated

I want to disable suggestions for widgets that are marked as deprecated by flutter. I've turned off he show deprecated suggestions in vs code but doesn't seem to work. It would be helpful to narrow down the suggestions to one's that are going to stay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below, put this line just above the top of deprecated widgets:

```
// ignore: deprecated_member_use
```

Comment: This isn't what I was asking. You might've read wrong.